# JVM locks JAR files on startup

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, javassist

I've implemented a custom ClassLoader which is set via system property `-Djava.system.class.loader=com.MyClassLoader`. The CL contains a static initializer that invokes some code (before any class is loaded) manipulating the byte code of a class file within a jar (maven dependency) using the javassist library. This works fine, except that i cannot replace the old jar with the new one since the JVM is locking the file and only releases it when it terminates. Why is that and how can I enforce the JVM to release the lock?

Here is a little code snippet:

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

static {
   ...
   modifyJar();
}

private static void modifyJar(){        
   URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL[] urls = urlClassLoader.getURLs();
    for(URL url : urls) {
      //find matching jar and modify byte code
    }        
    replaceJarFile(metaData);
}

private static void replaceJarFile(JarMetaData jmd){
     //add modified class to new jar file
     JarFile jar = new JarFile(jmd.getJarFile());
     ...

    //this method call returns false, jar is locked by another process (the JVM)
    if(oldJarFile.delete()){
       ...
    }  
  }
}
```

OS: Windows 10

JDK version: 1.8.0_131

Comment: Are you closing your `JarFile` after you are done loading classes from it?

Comment: The issue is not my newly created jar file, but the jar dependency loaded by the `URLClassLoader`. I don't have a handle on that file.

Comment: URLClassLoader will keep jar files open until it is closed. That is how it works. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#close()

Comment: OK, thanks for the hint. But if I close the URLClassLoader of the main thread, than no more jars are loaded and I'll run into ClassNotFoundExceptions. So how can I delegate the jar loading mechanism to a custom URLClassLoader in order ro load the jar myself after the byte code modifications?

Comment: Just create a new URLClassLoader and use that one to load modified jar. Then close it when you need to reload a new jar.

Comment: I've added the URL of the new jar to the classpath but the the JVM still loads the old jar. I've checked the location of the modified class `System.out.println(ModifiedClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());` Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that adding the URL of the new jar location to the URLClassLoader has no effect since the old URL still exists in the classpath and is loaded before mine.

Comment: You need to load old and new jar using a new URLClassLoader and not the one used by system classloader.

Comment: The problem is, instantiating a new CL throws the following exception `IllegalStateException: recursive invocation`

Comment: The JVM’s behavior is reasonable and there’s no reason why changing the original jar should work while the JVM is running. After all, that would be a permanent change, so why not doing it *before* starting the JVM, e.g. in a different JVM? If you want to change class definitions on-the-fly, you should write a Java Agent. For those JVMs supporting Java Agents, the [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) offers everything needed.

Comment: @Holger I indeed thought about executing this piece of code in a separate process but I preferred a solution that requires to manage just one single process.After reading lots of blog/forum posts I was sure that it has to work somehow, but the code samples probably apply only to jars which are not visible to the JVM, i.e. outside its classpath. However, I took a look at the Instrumentation API and managed it to transfer the code into an own javaagent library.It works perfectly.Many thanks for the pointers.If you change your comment to an answer I would mark it as accepted. Also thx to tsolakp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has never been specified that changing the jars in use by a JVM should be possible. And the JVM is locking the jars for quiet a long time now. Changing the classes within a jar in use would also bear the semantic problem of how to handle modifications to already loaded classes or even an ongoing class loading overlapping with a write.

Since modifying the jar would be a permanent change, the most reasonable approach for that would be doing it before starting the JVM, e.g. in a different JVM.

But if you want to change class definitions on-the-fly, you should write a Java Agent. For those JVMs supporting Java Agents, the [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) offers everything needed, e.g. transforming classes at load time or even redefining already loaded classes.
It also offers a standard way of adding jar files to the bootstrap or system class path, whereas assuming that the application class loader is a subclass of `URLClassLoader` will start to fail with Java 9.